# Incorrect reading cyrillic utf-8 symbols from MySQL with Python

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, utf-8, pydev

Here is my code, which connects to database, and inserts russian word into database:

```
import mysql.connector

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
            cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='password',
                                      host='123.123.123.123',
                                      database='db_name',
                                      charset='utf8',
                                      collation='utf8_general_ci',
                                      use_unicode=True)
        except BaseException as ex: 
            print('Error: ' + str(ex))
            cnx.close()
        else:
            print('Connections succesful!')
            cnx.set_charset_collation('utf8', 'utf8_general_ci')
            cursor = cnx.cursor()
    print(cnx.charset)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) values ('привет!')") #means 'Hello!' in russian
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test_referers")
    print(cursor.fetchall())
```

And here is what I get:

```
Connection succesful!
utf8
(1, u'\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442!')
```

Such output appears in both Python interpreter console and Eclipse PyDev.

Kindly help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output is valid Unicode. Python echoes that back to you with Unicode escape values (`\uxxxx`) because the row consists of a tuple with two items; when printing a tuple it's contents are represented as python literals instead.

If you were to use the following code:

```
print(cursor.fetchall()[1])
```

instead it would print:

```
привет!
```

You can test this by printing the literal value with the python prompt:

```
>>> print u'\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442!'
привет!
```

Comment: Thank you! I will save much time thanks to your answer. ps correct code is "print(cursor.fetchall()[0][1])"

Comment: @GillBates: glad to have been of help!

Comment: Also I want to ask - Is it possible to set prefix 'u' (or gain effect of its) for variables? For example unicode characters of str() representation of tuple, returned by fetchall()?